# Why does corona discharge generate ozone?

Tags: electricity

When a corona discharge occurs for instance in a laser printer, ozone is generated.

What is the mechanism that produce ozone for high voltage discharge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ozone is produced from the [reaction of oxygen atoms with $O_2$ molecules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone-oxygen_cycle). The oxygen atoms are produced from fission of $O_2$ molecules due to inelastic scattering of electrons in the plasma generated by the corona.

Bear in mind that ozone production in a corona discharge is not a precise process. Scattering of high energy electrons from gas molecules produces a range of reactive species. For example corona discharges produce oxides of nitrogen as well as ozone. Ozone is produced mainly because the $O + O_2 \rightarrow O_3$ reaction is fast, and because air contains a lot of oxygen.

Comment: But air contains more nitrogen than oxygen right?

Comment: Yes, but breaking the $N_2$ triple bond requires more energy ($473kJ/mol$) than the $O_2$ double bond ($249kJ/mol$) so it happens less often.

Comment: @BowlOfRed: I doubt the difference in bond strength is significant given that the electron energies are far greater than either bond strength. There may well be a difference in the cross sections for inelastic scattering of electrons, but to be honest I don't know what the difference is or how it arises.

Comment: @nowox: to explain the relative amounts of ozone and oxides of nitrogen produced would require a detailed study of the kinetics of the reactions. I assume this has been done, and is out there in Googleland somewhere, but in any case that would be better discussed on the [Chemistry SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).